# When i build the Telegram App it shows "SSignalKit/SSignalKit.h file not found"?

Tags: objective-c, xmppframework

I cloned Telegram App but compilation fail with "SSignalKit/SSignalKit.h file not found"

What should i do to fix this?

[image]

Comment: This says telegraph not telegram

Comment: Where did you found that code ?

Comment: sorry about that this is right link: https://github.com/peter-iakovlev/Telegram

Comment: You should try to get support on the GitHub project instead

Comment: https://github.com/peter-iakovlev/Telegram/issues

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the git submodules as well, this can be done with:

```
 git submodule update --init --recursive
```

After successfully doing the that, build should fail because it cannot find the file `config.h`,
this can be fixed like described [here](https://github.com/peter-iakovlev/Telegram/issues/34#issuecomment-205094852).

**Note:** the submodules are linked with their ssh link, so if you don't have an authorized ssh for github on your mac, you either [need to create one](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/) or change the links to the submodules repos from ssh links to https links (which can be found under `[PROJECT_ROOT]/.gitmodules` and `[PROJECT_ROOT]/.git/config`